# Using eof or end-of-input in ff match?

Tags: match, raku, eof

I have a huge data file in the following format:

```
section 1
data 1
end section

section n # n is a large number > 10000
data n
end section
```

The marker for the end of each section is the same, "end section". I need to frequently get a section and then another section to the end of the file. I do so in 2 steps:

```
cat dataFile | perl6 -ne 'my $n=1234; .say if /section \s $n/ ff /end \s section/' > neededPart
cat dataFile | perl6 -ne 'my $n=4321; .say if /section \s $n/ ff *' >> neededPart
```

This is cumbersome when I have do it many times. I wonder if perl6 has something like end-of-input or eof in match, so that I can just do in one line:

```
cat dataFile | perl6 -ne '.say if /1234 || 4321/ ff /"end section" || endOfFile/' > neededPart
```

Using the following does not work:

```
/1234 || 4321/ ff (/end/ or *)
/1234 || 4321/ ff ($_ ~~ /end/ or *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use two `ff` conditions instead of a single. For example:

```
perl6 -ne '.say if (/1234/ ff /"end section"/) || (/4321/ ff *)' <dataFile
```